# Autodownload for firefox in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, download-manager

I want to autodownload the file when clicking on particular link. But, here pop up window asking for open and save option gets opened in selenium with firefox browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/text"+",application/pdf"+",txt/csv/xls"+",text/plain")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/text"+",application/pdf"+",txt/csv/xls"+"text/plain" )
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", tempDir)
url = "http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/generate-file-to-download-demo.html" #sample website
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= firefox_path, firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)

inpbox = driver.find_element_by_id("textbox")
inpbox.send_keys("Lorem Ipsum \r\n")
driver.find_element_by_id("create").click()
import time
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("link-to-download").click()
```

Here I am working on Python 3.6 and Firefox 60.0.1 version.

Comment: Do you want to download it physically, or you want to make sure, that file will be downloaded, if you click on the link?

Comment: I want to download it to the particular location.

Comment: You can have a look here. https://github.com/chriskiehl/pyrobot.

Comment: That's Good. But I want to do this with only selenium if possible.

Comment: Here `"text/plain"` probably should be `",text/plain"`.